# Weird behavior in chrome's javascript .width property

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This problem drives me crazy!

In chrome, i have this line:

```
console.debug(a[q],a[q].width);
```

I look in the console and the values are different! 
when I look in the width property of the object it shows 46, but the output of a[q].width is 24!
It seems hard to believe but this is true. Is there a point of giving you all the code, because really this is one line and different values in the same line...

the problem happens only in chrome...
is there any chance that chrome interprets a[q].width differently than just displaying the contents of a[q]?

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: it's complicated to reproduce it there. but it's in my live site. look in the console:  http://www.israelinsidethemovie.com   you may need to refresh to get this. another weird thing!

Comment: I just checked `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.jerusalemonlineu.com/blog">BLOG</a>`, it's both 50.

Comment: no, you need to refresh. that's another weird thing. you get different output in the console after refresh

Comment: I got the same, please note `offsetWidth` and `width` is not same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhere in your code, (before the current line), the widh was changed from 24 to 46 for some reason, and the code that make the change - doesn't work in Chrome.

If this is the possible reason - you should try put a equivalent code - that would make the same difference that was made in other browsers - in Chrome too. You can do a Chrome Only code inside this:

> ```
> /*Chrome and Opera only */ 
> @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)  
> { 
>     #myId { width:46px; } 
> }
> ```

Anyway, that's how you can force the width in chrome. After you're doing it - I'm not sure Chrome will have a reason to play with you like that !